# I am trying to preview my SSRS report on Visual studio 2013, and it is throwing this error

Tags: reporting-services

Image if the error that is displayed when trying to preview

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the problem is with the VS project/solution. Are you opening the project from a local drive with full access? Check permissions on the project's folder and in particular it's bin folder.

Comment: Thank you, it turned out that I had the same report running in a different VS window.